# Maximum value of multiple summarized value

Tags: crystal-reports

I have difficulty in getting a maxiumu value from a multiple summarized values in group section. For example, I summarized budget, commitment, cost and forecast total in a report group section, and now in group footer I need pick a maximum value of the four totals. How should I do it?

Edit............................................................

```
1) Sum ({@Total Contracted Value}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}), 
2) Sum ({@Current Budget}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}) 
3) Sum ({@Costs to Date}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}) 
4) Sum ({@Projected Final PM Input}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code})
```

and I need to find the highest value within the four totals in group footer section

Comment: Hello Sarah. I don't know exactly but, I think you should create formula field where you can write to check which value is greater than previous one.

Comment: @Sarah I am edited your question to add your edits... so that question will be more meaningful

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two formula field for that 1st for variable initialization and 2nd for condition which value is bigger than other.

1: Create a first formula field and write down the following code. Give the name of that formula field to `Initialization`.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar dMax := 0;
```

Then place that formula field in the Report Header section.

2: Now, create another formula field and write down following code in that formula field.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
//dont initialize the 0 in this variable we have already initialized in 1st formula field
numbervar dMax; 

//Following condition will check that current sum of that field is greater than 
//values stored dMax variable. If the condition is satisfied then value will be initialized
//In dMax variable.
if (IsNull(Sum({TableName.FieldName}, {TableName.GroupField})) = False AND 
     Sum({TableName.FieldName}, {TableName.GroupField}) > dMax)
    dMax:=Sum({TableName.FieldName}, {TableName.GroupField}); 

dMax;
```

Now, put this formula field where the summarized value is calculated. for example in group footer.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to find out the max value withing the four group total. then write down the following code in your formula field and put it in the group footer.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar dMax1:=0;
if (Sum ({@Total Contracted Value}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code})) > (Sum ({@Current Budget}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}))
     dMax1:=Sum ({@Total Contracted Value}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code});
else
     dMax1:=Sum ({@Current Budget}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code});


numbervar dMax2:=0;
if (Sum ({@Costs to Date}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}) ) > (Sum ({@Projected Final PM Input}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}))
     dMax2:=Sum ({@Costs to Date}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code});
else
     dMax2:=Sum ({@Projected Final PM Input}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code});

if (dMax1 < dMax2)
    dMax1 := dMax2;

dMax1;
```

Comment: it doesn't work.  it doesn't pick the maximum value from the four group totals (budget, commitment, cost, forecast)...

Comment: my four group totals are:

Comment: 1)  Sum ({@Total Contracted Value}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}),  2)  Sum ({@Current Budget}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code})    3) Sum ({@Costs to Date}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code})    4) Sum ({@Projected Final PM Input}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code})
    and I need to find the highest value within the four totals in group footer section

Comment: are you sure !! you just want to find out which value is bigger from all of these four?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the arrays...

Store all values in an array and in group footer just take the maximum of the array.

When you summarize the value at the same time store the values in array and retrive maximum from the array. Place below formula after summarizied data in group

```
//@Storedatainarray  
Shared StringVar Array x;

x:=x+totext(Sum ({field}, {@group}));
```

Now create one more formula @display

```
EvaluateAfter(@Storedatainarray);
Whileprintingrecords;
Shared StringVar Array x;

Maximum(x);
```

Let me know how it goes?

Edit....................................

Create a formula `@Display` and write below code in `group footer`:

```
Shared StringVar Array x;

    x[1]:= Sum ({@Total Contracted Value}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code});
    x[2]:= Sum ({@Current Budget}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code});
    x[3]:= Sum ({@Costs to Date}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code});
    x[4]:= Sum ({@Projected Final PM Input}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code});
Maximum(x);
```

Comment: it doesn't work.  the four columns were summarized in different method, but somehow in the group footer total section, I need to compare the four totals and pick the maximum value.  For example, if total budget is 5000, commitment is 3000, cost to date is 6000, forecast is 5500.  I need to have a formula to show 6000.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the report strucutre so that i can understand the exact issue

Comment: 1) Sum ({@Total Contracted Value}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}), 2) Sum ({@Current Budget}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}) 3) Sum ({@Costs to Date}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}) 4) Sum ({@Projected Final PM Input}, {JCM_MASTER__COST_CODE.Cost_Code}) and I need to find the highest value within the four totals in group footer section